# How to send emails to multiple recipients using the same form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I have an invite feature associated with each scoreboard. Where each scoreboard has_many sent_invitations and each invitation belongs_to a scoreboard. The feature works perfectly fine. The current interface allows the admin to type in each email address separately to send invites.

However, I wanted to improve on the interface by allowing the admin to type in multiple email addresses in the same form separated by a comma or highlighting in a way to let users know that the email is done and then sending one email to all those email addresses.

I am not sure how to get my form to accept multiple emails separated by commas or by any other means? I don't think rails provides a different form helper for this. How would I process this in my controller? How would I set up the regex for this? I have never implemented a form which accepts multiple email addresses and then sends one email to each one of them. Any information on this topic would be very helpful.

The code for the new form.

```
<h1>Invitation</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class= "col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
      <%= form_for [@scoreboard, @invitation] do |f| %> <!-- you have to pass in the scoreboard id into the forms as well -->
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

        <%= f.label :recipient_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :recipient_name, class: "form-control", placeholder: "First and last name." %>

        <%= f.label :recipient_email, placeholder: "Enter email" %>
        <%= f.text_field :recipient_email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter a valid email address." %>

        <%= f.submit "Send Invitation", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The invitation controller code is given below:

```
def create
        @scoreboard = Scoreboard.find(params[:scoreboard_id])
        @invitation = @scoreboard.sent_invitations.build(invitation_params)
        if @invitation.save && User.exists?(email: @invitation.recipient_email) == true
            flash[:success] = "Invitation sent successfully"
            UserMailer.registered_invitation_email(@scoreboard, @invitation_email).deliver_now
            redirect_to new_scoreboard_invitation_path
         elsif
             @invitation.save && User.exists?(email: @invitation.recipient_email) == false
             UserMailer.non_registered_invitation_email(@scoreboard, @invitation).deliver_now
             flash[:success] = "Invitation sent successfully"
             redirect_to new_scoreboard_invitation_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write another method to split the email params with something like `emails = params[:recipient_email].split(",")`. That will create an array of all the emails that were separated by commas. Then do:
`@invitations = []
 emails.each {|email| @invitations << @scoreboard.sent_invitations.build(email)}` or something like that.